# MongoDB/Mongoose unique constraint on Date field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have declared a unique index on a schema like so:

```js
var stateChangeEventSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  client_timestamp: { type: Date, required: true, unique: true },
  state: { type: String, required: true }
})
```

And am able to insert a document with identical timestamps. I would expect a constraint violation. I thought it might be because it's on an embedded document, but I tried on a regular document, and it still allows it. What am I missing?

**Edit**: I found the issue. I was failing to create another index, which for whatever reason prevented any other indexes from being created.

I found this by using:

```
StateChange.on('index', function (err) {
  if (err) console.error(err);
})
```

which netted: `err: 'Index with name: _id_ already exists with different options'`

This occurred because I had the following line: `_id: { type: String, unique: true, 'default': shortId.generate }` (edited out in the original code for clarity - didn't think it would affect anything).

Removing that line allowed the `client_timestamp` index to be created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you already had duplicate values before you made this change.

Here is a test case. Have two documents in your collection like this before you deploy an index:

```js
{ "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-06-02T04:09:22.683Z") }
{ "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-06-02T04:09:22.683Z") }
```

Then with the basic listing:

```js
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

    var stateChange = mongoose.Schema({
      timestamp: { type: Date, required: true, unique: true }
    });

    var Change = mongoose.model( 'Change', stateChange );

    var date = new Date();

    var change = new Change({
      timestamp: date
    });

    change.save(function(err,change) {

      if ( err )
        throw err;

      console.log( change );

      var new_change = new Change({
        timestamp: date
      });

      new_change.save(function(err,change) {

        if ( err )
          throw err;

        console.log( change );

      });

    });
```

You'll see both documents are added. But the thing here is that the index did not deploy because that caused an error you did not see. You can check this in the shell.

```js
db.changes.getIndicies()
```

Which will show your unique index was not created:

```js
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "test.changes"
    }
]
```

If you started again and only had one document from the original

```js
{ "timestamp" : ISODate("2014-06-02T04:09:22.683Z") }
```

Then the code sample above creates the index and produces an error in the second insert:

```js
{ __v: 0,
  timestamp: Mon Jun 02 2014 14:29:44 GMT+1000 (EST),
  _id: 538bfdb8961376867ae42e61 }

/xxxxx/node_modules/mongoose/lib/utils.js:413
    throw err;
          ^
MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: test.changes.$timestamp_1  dup key: { : new Date(1401683384647) }
```

The index created properly this time:

```js
[
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "key" : {
                    "_id" : 1
            },
            "name" : "_id_",
            "ns" : "test.changes"
    },
    {
            "v" : 1,
            "unique" : true,
            "key" : {
                    "timestamp" : 1
            },
            "name" : "timestamp_1",
            "ns" : "test.changes",
            "background" : true,
            "safe" : null
    }
]
```

You are going to need to go through your data to remove the existing duplicates or just accept the usage of the [`dropDups`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/#drop-duplicates) option to automatically remove them for you.

Also see the documentation tutorial: [Create A Unique Index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-a-unique-index/)

Comment: Hmm. I have deleted my database and tried again. The index is not correctly created.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra You are doing something wrong here that you are not explaining. The case as shown above is produced from a blank database and is reproduce-able in the results.

Comment: Ahh, I have found it. Edited main post

Comment: Hmmmmmm this works on a non embedded document, but still fails when embedded.

Comment: @DominicBou-Samra I have no idea what you are asking. You seem to have found a problem in details not contained in your posted question. Are you now asking about more details not contained in your posted question?